# How to show the inside div(replacable) if I scrolled to the leftmost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Attached is the [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/j2W6wmrdZ4ucvzitbGLn?p=preview).I need to **show Div-2 in place of Div-1**, after user scrolled the Div-1 to the leftmost..can any one help me out?..

**HTML**

```
<div id="div-1" class="scrollable-div">
  <div class="div-inside">Div 1:After scrolling this I should get Div-2 inplace of Div-1</div>
</div>
<div id="div-2" class="scrollable-div">
    <div class="div-inside">Div 2:After scrolling this I should show "End-treatment"</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
                  $('#div-2').hide();
  $('#div-1').on('scroll', function () {
    if($(this).scrollLeft() + $(this).innerWidth() >= $(this)[0].scrollWidth) {
      $('#div-2').show();
    } else if($(this).scrollLeft() === 0) {
      $('#other-message').show();
    // Remove this part if you don't want your messages hidden again
    } else {
      $('#end-treatment').hide();
      $('#other-message').hide();
    }
  })
    $('#div-2').on('scroll', function () {
    if($(this).scrollLeft() + $(this).innerWidth() >= $(this)[0].scrollWidth) {
      $('#end-treatment').show();
    } else if($(this).scrollLeft() === 0) {
      $('#other-message').show();
    // Remove this part if you don't want your messages hidden again
    } else {
      $('#end-treatment').hide();
      $('#other-message').hide();
    }
  })

});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looks like you are asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: use "$('#div-1').hide();" when div1 scroll left after right.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammetCanTONBUL..working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Updated [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5dX12utyix5Ae2dDdU4n?p=preview) with answer given in above comment

```
jQuery(function ($)
      {
        $('#div-2').hide();

  $('#div-1').on('scroll', function () {
    if($(this).scrollLeft() + $(this).innerWidth() >= $(this)[0].scrollWidth) 
    {
         $('#div-2').show(1000);
         $('#div-1').hide();    
    } 
 })
```